# Update and publish in air 3.5?

Tags: ios, flash, air, publish

I need to publish an application with 3.5 to get it working on iPhone 5. I download de air 3.5 and install it, I downloaded the air 3.5 sdk wich are files and i don't know what to do and the thing is that in the publish setting I only have air 3.2 and not air 3.5 that is what I need. Someone knows what i'm missing? Are the sdk files that I have to copy in some place or something like that? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Try doing a Google search with the terms: "update AIR SDK in Flash Professional" - I'd offer more help but it seems like the steps vary depending on what version of Flash Pro you are using (CS5, CS6, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Sunil D. I couldnt find it. Here is the solution i found to update Air SDK with Flash CS5.5 or CS6 http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow/enable-the-latest-air-sdk-in-flash-professional-cs5-5/